# Multiple VMs from different Tenants

Tags: multi-tenant, snort, intrusion-detection, vlan

I have a system running two tenants where each tenant contains multiple VMs, I am running snort agent to detect any intrusion from both tenants, so how to know which VM belong to which tenant that generates the intrusion and append this info to snort alert?

Thanks

Comment: [tag:osi] has nothing to do with this question, or with anything else much.